# Input fixed length sequence of frames to CNN

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, conv-neural-network

I want my pytorch CNN to take as input a sequence of length `SEQ_LEN` of 32x32 RGB images concatenated along channels dimension. Therefore, a single input of the network has shape `(32, 32, 3, SEQ_LEN)`. How should I define my CNN input layer?

The common way

```py
SEQ_LEN = 10
input_conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=SEQ_LEN, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3)

BATCH_SIZE = 64
frames = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(BATCH_SIZE, SEQ_LEN, 3, 32, 32))
frames_tensor = torch.tensor(frames)

input_conv(frames_tensor)
```

gives the error

> RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [32, 10, 3, 3], but got 5-dimensional input of size [64, 10, 3, 32, 32] instead

Comment: Why don't you just put the sequence into the batch dimension?

Comment: Because a batch is be composed by several of these sequences. Each sequence is a set of frames related to each other, and I need to perform some specific operations among only frames of the same sequence.

Comment: I.e. imagine that the network needs to predict the velocity of the object in the images, and therefore a single input needs to be the concatenation of several frames.

Comment: OK then this doesn't sound like a *2D* CNN at all.

Comment: Oh you're right! What I actually need is a Conv3d layer

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments, it sounds like your data is not fit for a *2D* convolutional neural network at all, and that a *3D* one ([`Conv3d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv3d.html)) would be more appropriate. As you can see from its documentation, its input shape is what you would expect.